# Interfaces in TypeScript vs Java

Tags: java, typescript

This fails in TypeScript...

```
interface A {
    getSomeBasicA():A;
    getSomeBetterA():BetterA;
}

interface BetterA extends A {
    getSomeBasicA():BetterA;
    doFancyAStuff():void;
}

interface B extends A {
    getSomeBetterA():BetterB;
}

interface BetterB extends B, BetterA {}
```

... with this message ...

```
error TS2430: Interface 'B' incorrectly extends interface 'A'.
  The types returned by 'getSomeBetterA().getSomeBasicA()' are incompatible between these types.
    Property 'doFancyAStuff' is missing in type 'A' but required in type 'BetterA'.
error TS2320: Interface 'BetterB' cannot simultaneously extend types 'B' and 'BetterA'.
  Named property 'getSomeBasicA' of types 'B' and 'BetterA' are not identical.
error TS2320: Interface 'BetterB' cannot simultaneously extend types 'B' and 'BetterA'.
  Named property 'getSomeBetterA' of types 'B' and 'BetterA' are not identical.
```

... while this works in Java ...

```
public interface A {
    public A getSomeBasicA();
    public BetterA getSomeBetterA();
}

public interface BetterA extends A {
    public BetterA getSomeBasicA();
    public void doFancyAStuff();
}

public interface B extends A {
    public BetterB getSomeBetterA();
}

public interface BetterB extends B, BetterA {
    
}
```

... and I wonder why? Is it not type safe (how could it be broken, why does the Java compiler allow it)? Is there a name for the feature that one compiler supports and the other doesn't?

Comment: From my understanding the interface concept is only similar but quite different in both languages. In TS you don't need to declare an interface on any classes, the compiler just checks the object given mets the properties declared in the interface. This allows interop with plain JS objects and objects you don't have direct control over. The extends keyword on the other hand is primarly thought to extend the existing interface, not changing it's definition via override. This has less to do with the compiler itself but the way both languages work out at runtime

Comment: This is a limitation / missing feature in TS, see [microsoft/TypeScript#16936](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16936) for the relevant feature request.  Will write up an answer when I get to a real computer, unless someone gets here first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you've seen, TypeScript requires that when [extending multiple interfaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#extending-interfaces) via the comma notation (e.g., `interface X extends Y, Z { ... }`), any member names common to more than one of the parent interfaces need to have *identical types*.

The definition of `BetterB` runs afoul of this restriction; it cannot be declared to extend both `B` and `BetterA`. `B` has a `getBasicA` member of type `() => A`, while `BetterA` has a `getBasicA` member of type `() => BetterA`.  Those types are not identical, so you get an error there, which ends up unraveling the whole thing because your interface definitions are recursive.

---

This requirement that common properties in an extension of multiple interfaces have identical types is perhaps more restrictive than it needs to be.  There is an open feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#16936](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16936) asking to allow common members to have non-identical but "compatible" types (presumably meaning that the types have some overlap).  It's not 100% clear what the behavior should be in this situation; perhaps the new interface's property type would be an [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#intersection-types) of the property types from each parent interface, or maybe some more sophisticated selection process could occur.  But in any case, it's just not part of the language as of TS4.1.

To reiterate: it's not that what you're trying to do is not type safe, it's just not supported.

---

So, what can you do?  One notable thing about TypeScript is that the type system is [structural](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#structural-type-system) and not *nominal* as in Java.  Types are compared by their *shape* in TypeScript, not by their *declarations*.  In Java, if you can't *declare* that `interface X extends Y, Z`, then you can't *use* an `X` when you are asked for a `Y` or a `Z`.  TypeScript has no such restriction: if `X`'s structure is compatible with both `Y` and `Z`, you can use an `X` in place of a `Y` or a `Z` even if the declaration of `X` doesn't mention `Y` or `Z` explicitly.

That means if we can figure out what member names and types we'd like to see on `BetterB`, we can just define `BetterB` as having that shape without explicitly saying `extends B, BetterA`.  If we do it right, it will automatically extend those interfaces.

The simplest way I can think of to do this is:

```
interface BetterB extends Pick<B, "getSomeBetterA">, BetterA { }
```

Here we are still extending `BetterA`, but instead of explicitly extending all of `B`, we are using the [`Pick` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys) to say that we only want to extend the part of `B` with a `getSomeBetterA` member.  The offending `getBasicA` method is excluded, so there's no error.  And since `BetterA`'s `getBasicA` method is assignable to `B`'s `getBasicA` method, `BetterB` still extends `B` structurally, as can be seen here:

```
declare const bB: BetterB;
const b: B = bB; // okay
```

There is no error assigning a value of type `BetterB` to a variable of type `B`.  You didn't declare that `BetterB extends B` but it happened anyway.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.3#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4ChnIOYRgDKA9gLYQBCcAzsAqgBQCUAXGgNw76GkWWFIUJm2QCwQ1FwC+WLKCHwkYwdHQQAHpBAATGmkzcCxclVr0R7cZI7JuOkgDE4IBAE9URMAFcYMFuwAbiTAOjJyCtBKKJTImtp6Bti4xnxUqsIBKhLQlOHy4FGIMRmx8RC6+gAK9ADWADyUADTIAESpptZqrQB8LV3CmMiyWDoQCAA2cFAoCCQgNGDIAEaUVqVccwtLy1bIALwrecgA9CfIJLVwbi0AKm4ADhBECFDAD0sOEPozc3ggwAAXigwAALOBLAZlLQVRKxRZQbwIHxQOATCZuIA)

Comment: `Pick` works, as you said. Another idea from the feature request you linked to: restating methods (at least `getSomeBasicA(): BetterA;` in `BetterB`) also works (verbose but simple). I don't know yet, what I am going to do in practice but thanks to you I can now definitly please the TypeScript compiler. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Just because it works in Java doesn't mean it should work on Typescript. It's two very different things. For starters Typescript relies on duck typing and Java doesn't.

if you want to combine multiple interfaces it's better to use mapped types instead of extends a lot of times.

I wrote about that on medium [here](https://medium.com/better-programming/mastering-typescripts-mapped-types-5fa5700385eb) check it out, it should probably help

Comment: "too" -> "two".

Comment: The mapped type combination possibilities seem interesting. I am definitely not using them to their full potential. Thank you for sharing your knowledge. Btw. I don't want to make TypeScript a Java clone. I will gladly do TypeScript in the most TypeScript way I know.